# input a list of 2D coordinates in python from user

Tags: python, input, coordinates

The user needs to input a set of coordinates like so (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)

The code I wrote for that looks like this:

```
def get_coords():
    #user_input = raw_input("Enter a list of points. For example (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)\n")
    print "Enter a list of points. For example (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)\n"
    uin = sys.stdin.readline().strip() 
    try:
    #coords = map(int, uin.split(' '))
    coords = [tuple(map(int, point.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(','))) for point in uin.split(' ')]
    return coords
    except ValueError:
    print "Please enter the coordinates in the format mentioned"
    exit()
```

I'm sure there is a better, more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the spaces with `','` and then apply `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> strs = '(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)'
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(strs.replace(' ',','))
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))
```

Using regex, this would work on any amount of spaces:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = '(0, 0)  (0, 1) ( 1, 1)    ( 1,  0)'
>>> literal_eval(re.sub('(\))(\s+)(\()','\g<1>,\g<3>',strs))
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Although, if I add the commas in the input itself, like "(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)" and remove the replace() part from the code, it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @meenakshi It should work fine: `literal_eval("(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)")`

Comment: The first example doesn't work for `'(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)'.replace(' ',',')`. You get `'(0,0),,(0,1),,(1,1),,(1,0)'`, as you would expect. It would be better to use `split()` and then check if each substring ends with ')'; if not, use `string.rstrip()` with the `chars` argument as `', '`. Or something like that.

The difference in your answer and your comment is the lack of `.replace()` in your comment - of course, without it, it works fine!

Comment: @2rs2ts There are no commas in the example I've shown in my answer.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If you don't input commas, you need to do `.replace(' ',',')`, but if you do, you need to NOT do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> uin = raw_input("coords: ").split()
coords: (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,0)
>>> uin
['(0,0)', '(0,1)', '(1,1)', '(1,0)']
>>> coords = [literal_eval(coord) for coord in uin]
>>> coords
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
```

In your file, you can just write this. Replace the prompt with whatever you like.

```
from ast import literal_eval
try:
    coords = [literal_eval(coord) for coord in raw_input("coords: ").split()]
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter the coordinates in the format mentioned"
    exit()
```

`literal_eval()` [raises an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/691859) if the code isn't safe. [See the docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Regular `eval()` is bad because it can execute arbitrary code which your user inputs!

Comment: Yup, I avoid eval() on user input. I didn't know about literal_eval(), but I do now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add in commas between the tuples and you can safely evaluate the string into a tuple of tuples:

```
import ast

def get_coords():
    print "Enter a list of points. For example (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)"
    points = raw_input()

    while True:
        try:
            return ast.literal_eval(points)
        except SyntaxError:
            print "Please enter the coordinates in the format mentioned"
```

You'll get a result similar to:

```
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))
```

And if you absolutely need a list, just pass it through `list()`:

```
            return list(ast.literal_eval(points))
```